# Can't get into BIOS. I messed up boot priorities and probably enabled fast boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bios

I have Ubuntu, Processor - Intel, Motherboard - MSI.
Before all of this, I could get into BIOS by typing F11 when the it says enter F11.
Now it's not even saying to enter F11. It's just a black screen for sometime and opens desktop right away.

Comment: Usual first step is to hold down the delete key whilst booting to get you into the bios, don't wait for a message! If you are using UEFI then hitting esc multiple times might get you into UEFI. Holding down the shift will get you the grub menu.

Comment: Second step is to disconnect the drives and network. If the system fails to boot anything else you can hope it will fall back to the bios or uefi shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions. Tried to hold delete button while powering on, but nothing happened. Just black screen for like 5 minutes. Somehow when i tried these f11, esc, del it's just like freezing out and didn't even goes to desktop.

So, i took out my videocard, found under it the cmos battery, took it out for 1,5 minute and put it back. It worked.

I don't really get into inside of a computer, so it was a bit frightening for me to go there and take out cmos. Didnt know it even existed. Hope this will help someone in future

Comment: turns out enabling virtualization in BIOS does the screen go black and open desktop right away after

Comment: For the benefit of others... Do not hold down the DELETE key *while* powering on. Power on, and once the screen goes blank (very quickly, possibly only 1/10th of a second or less, indicating the BIOS has finished initializing the video display subsection and will begin to check for keyboard events), then hold down DELETE. Depending on how fast the BIOS proceeds, you may only have a fraction of a second to press it to get the BIOS attention. Other common keys to do so are INSERT, ESC, F10, F11, F12... Your mainboard documentation should tell you which key it expects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command [`efibootmgr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/efibootmgr.8.html) (from the package also named [`efibootmgr`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/efibootmgr)) to alter UEFI settings from the OS:

> `-t | --timeout seconds`
> Boot Manager timeout, in seconds.
>
> `-T | --delete-timeout`
> Delete Timeout variable.

So if the system already set up the correct mount point (`/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/`) as read/write, this command should set a 5 seconds timeout before booting on the default UEFI boot entry:

```
sudo efibootmgr -t 5
```

giving you more time to find how to stop the boot process in order to enter the UEFI settings.

The command above is safe, but stay careful when using `efibootmgr`, some options can have unwelcome effects.

Answer (score -1):

You can reset BIOS settings by clearing the motherboard RTC RAM, boot into BIOS and change the settings as you like. Check the motherboard user guide for info on how to do this.